# how to send SMS through a phone connected to PC in delphi code?

Tags: delphi, sms

how to send SMS through a mobile phone connected to PC in delphi code?

Comment: Doc ref: `ETS 300 585 (GSM 07.05 version 4.8.1): April 1997` (edition is not matterm tho)

Comment: Use TurboPower AsyncPro SMS messaging component.